# Rewrite unlimited directory depth

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&other=$3&ajax=0 [L]
```

And when I go to this url:

http://www.example.com/test/main/cat/monkey

my `print_r()`

looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [page] => test/main
    [action] => cat
    [other] => monkey
    [ajax] => 0
)
```

But the output I would like to see looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [page] => test
    [action] => main
    [other] => cat/monkey
    [ajax] => 0
)
```

It shouldn't matter how many items com after the "action" it should append them to "other" what is wrong with my rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.+` is greedy, so it'll gobble up as much text that it can while satisfying the rest of the expression as it can. You can change the pattern to `[^/]+` instead if you don't want it to match slashes:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1&action=$2&other=$3&ajax=0 [L]
```